# Eigenvalues and eigenstates of $\hat{L}=\sqrt{\hat{L}^2}=\sqrt{\hat{L}^2_x+\hat{L}^2_y+\hat{L}^2_z}$ (without squaring)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, eigenvalue, quantum-states

I know that $$ \hat{L}^2 \left| l,m \right> = \hbar^2 l (l+1) \left| l,m \right> .$$ Does this mean that $$ \hat{L} \left| l,m \right> = \hbar \sqrt{l (l+1)} \left| l,m \right> ? $$ If so, why? If not, what is the result of $\sqrt{\hat{L}^2} \left| l,m \right>$?

Comment: It is more common to isolate the operator whose eigenvalue is $\ell$.

Comment: And which is this operator?

Comment: how do you *define* the operator $\sqrt{\hat L^2}$?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I would answer (not OP) "spectrally" but then OPs question is a definition - basically.

Comment: @BenceRacskó ergo my question :-)

Comment: And also for some reason I downvoted this question, which was probably accident, but cannot undo it now. Sorry OP!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform good question. Basically I was looking for the mean value of magnetic field at a point produced by an electron in the hydrogen atom and I arrived to an expression of the form $B=\dots L$ so in quantum mechanics this would be something like $\hat{B} = \dots \hat{L}$ and so the possible values of $B$ are $B = \dots \hbar \sqrt{l(l+1)}$. This is where my question started.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it does mean that. $\hat L^2$ can be diagonalized in the way your wrote, and if you just square root the eigenvalues of a diagonalized operator, you have successfully square rooted the operator.

Having said that, you won't usually see people discuss $\sqrt{\hat L^2}$ because its a tad artificial. Indeed, the only way *to* define it is to take the square root of $\hat L^2$, which has a natural definition using the rotation generators.

Answer (score 1):

My comment was: "It is more common to isolate the operator whose eigenvalue is ℓ".

To which you commented

> And which is this operator?

The answer is $$
\hat O= \sqrt{(\hat L^2/\hbar ^2 + 1/4 ) }~~ -1/2,
$$
so, that
$$
\hat O |lm\rangle= l~ |lm\rangle.
$$

It is frequently used in formal constructions and deformation theory (quantum groups). You may tweak/adapt this to SU(1,1), if so inclined.